# Maven 3 + RELEASE version in dependency. Valid?

Tags: maven

Is a dependency entry like this, with RELEASE in version, still valid in Maven 3?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mygroup.mysubgroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myitem</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I read that it was deprecated when switching from Maven 2 to Maven 3.

If deprecated, what is the current recommended method to retrieve the latest released version of an artifact?

Comment: You should not use the `RELEASE` version anymore...and yes it is deprecated. So make simply a fixed version in there...The only way to use things like using the latest is to use version ranges which is not recommended.

Comment: @khmarbaise but buy the document in given link only tells about the maven plugin not about dependency and they are specific to LATEST not much for RELEASE. Is there any specific official  document  which tells the same.